# Best approach for structuring React component hierarchy and state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am fairly new to React and want to know the best way to implement my component hierarchy. I have 5 react components, structured like so:

```
<App>
  <PlaylistBar>
    <Playlist>
      <Video/>
      <Video/>
    </Playlist>
    <Playlist/>
    <Playlist/>
    ...etc
  </PlaylistBar>
  <Foo/>
</App>
```

Currently my code is structured so that `PlaylistBar` has state `playlists:[{id, name, length, etc.}]` - an array of playlist data (which it fetches asynchronously) which it then uses to generate the React `<Playlist>` components, which then in turn asynchronously fetch video data to generate `<Video>` components.

My issue is that on a playlist being clicked, I need to send all the playlist info along with its videos to the `<Foo>` component by passing it to a piece of state in `<App/>` called `currentPlaylist`, which then passes it to Foo

Currently, this is done by the entire playlist info object (name, id etc.) being passed to the playlist from `<PlaylistBar>` as a prop along with a handler for `onClick` being passed down from App. The playlist then appends its videos to the playlist info object (by adding a property `videos:[...]` containing the video info) and passes this back up to app.

This implementation seems very cumbersome, with the playlist having to receive its own info, modify it and send it back up the hierarchy. Is this implementation suitable, or should I change it?

For instance, `PlaylistBar` could fetch both the playlist and video info for each playlist. This would make the sending of playlist info to `Foo` much cleaner but make `Playlist` less self contained and more dependent on the components above it.

As a follow up question, should playlist info have a separate class declaration like so:

```
class PlaylistInfo {
    constructor(id, name, ...) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        etc.
    }
}
```

so that in `PlaylistBar` there is the state `playlist: [new PlaylistInfo(...), new PlaylistInfo()]`, or should it remain as just an object with no class implementation? Which is conventional in React development?

Comment: When creating React apps a viable approach is to have a "data layer" that contains logic, fetching, managing state, etc... and on the other hand, to have display components to present the data. This means you pointing in a good direction when you mention that you would group the fetching into one component.  In an advanced way, you can use React.Context API to reach out for the data from any of your components directly in your app. This way you can avoid passing props through multiple components.

Comment: Did you read about [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: I do know about using context. Is context the best approach for this? It would make <playlist> and <video> components (as well as everything under them) aware of the playlists (even though they may not use this context). This is not necessarily a problem but makes components aware of data they do not really need.